# Get content data from specific files from bigquery-public-data:github_repos different results with JOIN and WHERE

Tags: sql, github, google-bigquery

The most common way of getting content data from specific files [bigquery-public-data:github_repos](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/github) by name is like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents]
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_files]
  WHERE path = 'README.md'
))
```

This query gives me **14557** results.

I thought that running below query will give me the same ammount of results:

```
SELECT contents.*
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents] contents
INNER JOIN [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_files] files
  ON contents.id = files.id 
WHERE files.path = 'README.md'
```

But it ends up with **14645** results.

Why there is the difference between this two results, and witch one is a proper one for selecting content data of `README.md` file?

---

EDIT:

It looks like forked files without modification have the same id across others repos (forks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First query gives you all contents with files having path = 'README.md' no matter how many times that file id is present in files table

Second query gives you same content as many times as respective file is in files table - because of JOIN

You can run below to validate this

```sql
SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(contents.id)
FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents] contents
INNER JOIN [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_files] files
  ON contents.id = files.id 
WHERE files.path = 'README.md'
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is worth mention that my misunderstanding comes from the assumption that `id` in `files` table is unique and I thought that `contents.id = files.id` is 1 to 1 connection. Now I know that this `id` a simple file content hash. Where can I find this kind of information in a documentation?